# Alguma IDE parecida com Android Studio?

Tags: java, ide

Estou aprendendo Java, e me recomendam muito o Android Studio. Meu Notebook é um Core i3 com 4GB de ram, me falaram também que com 4 de ram é quase impossivel para tentar mexer com java.E verdade isso? Até porque não estou pensando em fazer upgrade no note só para programar em uma linguagem não. Existe alguma IDE parecida com Android Studio só que mais leve ou algo assim? Eu realmente achei um absurdo ter quase 8 de ram só para mexer nessa IDE.Eu sei que da para fazer um app até pelo bloco de notas,mas levaria muuuito mais tempo, dependendo do projeto. 
Obs : Nao precisa ser uma IDE que faça meu note voar de tão leve não, não travando muito a ponto de dar erro ou algo assim já está bom.

Comment: Java ou Android? Pra Java seria o IntelliJ, não o Android Studio. De qualquer forma, pra qualquer um dos dois, 6 GB é suficiente. 4 GB também, se você não faz questão de usar Windows. Tem várias distribuições Linux que gastam menos memória e sobre mais para a IDE.

Comment: Reforçando o que o @PabloAlmeida disse, você tem distribuições de linux bem leves, que cortam o peso que o proprio windows tem (que não é assim tão pouco) liberando assim mais memoria para o Android Studio. Pessoalmente acho que é a melhor aposta que tem.

Comment: Tenho 8Gb de RAM, a IDE não trava só por falta de RAM, mas por uso intenso de disco, aqui está usando 1.890Gb e trava se utilizar algum programa que usa muito o disco junto

Answer (score 0):

Meu notebook aparentemente tem quais as mesmas configuração que o seu, já consegui usar o android studio nele, depois que a IDE carrega da para mexer(demora muito), mas da umas travada.

você pode configurar o **eclipse** para ter o ambiente de desenvolvimentismo android -->   [nesse tutorial](http://www.pontov.com.br/site/android/276-configurando-ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-android-com-eclipse).

antigamente se usava o eclipse para ser criar apps android, só que a Google não recomenda mais, mas só por estudo vele apena.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a sua configuração eta até razoável se não for mexer com coisa muito pesada, uma opção é fazer um upgrade nessa memoria pra 8GB. 
Sobre a IDE, não sei se a melhor IDE para aprender Java é o Android Studio, ele é mais voltado para fazer aplicações com Patter Android. Se quiser uma IDE parecida com o Android Studio mais voltada para o Java, existe o IntelliJ Community que é do mesmo desenvolvedor do Android Studio, ambas são muito parecidas, e são tão pesadas quanto. Segue abaixo:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux

Sobre opções mais leves, voce pode tentar usar o Visual Studio Code com o plugin para programar em Java. Eu testei ele e funcionou razoavelmente bem e parece uma excelente opção para IDE mais level, a unica ressalva é que talvez, você precisa de algum conhecimento mais avançado da linguagem para configurar algumas coisas, entretanto isso também fará ganha conhecimento e talz. Segue abaixo:
https://code.visualstudio.com/download

E por ultimo temos também o bom e velho eclipse que em questão de peso, é um intermédio entre as duas opções acima, e também se não me engano, deve ser a IDE mais usada entre programadores Java. Segue abaixo:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/oxygen2